# Store a CAST to a variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, casting, set

A column in SQL had data in an image format. I used CAST and the data spits out in text, which is all great. The problem is the column has HTML tags. I'm trying to strip away HTML tags from a column that has been casted.

I've created a function to remove the HTML tags but now I need to call the function on that casted column.

/* Converting the image to text */

```
SELECT cast(cast(note as varbinary(max)) as varchar (max)) note
FROM NOTES
```

/*HTML Function*/

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripHTML] (@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Length INT
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText) SET @End = 
CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)) 
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1 WHILE @Start > 0
AND @End > 0
AND @Length > 0
BEGIN
SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText) SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
END
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
END
GO
```

THE PROBLEM CODE:

```
SELECT
       [Col1]
      ,[Col2]
      ,[Col3]
      ,[Col4]
      ,dbo.udf_StripHTML(cast(cast(note as varbinary(max)) as varchar (max)) note)
  FROM NOTES
```

How do I call the HTML function with the cast?

Comment: Your code running the HTML code after the casts.

Comment: It looks like you copied the alias you were using for the column in the previous query into the paranthesis for the function. Remove the word note. `dbo.udf_StripHTML(cast(cast(note as varbinary(max)) as varchar (max)))` or move it outside the last ) like this `dbo.udf_StripHTML(cast(cast(note as varbinary(max)) as varchar (max))) note`

Comment: This worked but I thought this would solve my initial problem. It did remove the tags but when I export as csv, the impact of those tags still remains. For example, an HTML tag on separating the line. The tag got stripped from the column but when exported as csv, the data was pushed to the next line. I was hoping that when removing the tags, the data would extract in the same format as in the column

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a syntax error. This should work:

```
SELECT
       [Col1]
      ,[Col2]
      ,[Col3]
      ,[Col4]
      ,[Note] = dbo.udf_StripHTML(cast(cast([note] as varbinary(max)) as varchar (max)))
FROM NOTES
```